# Invalid topic error with flasfka package

Tags: flask, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka with flask-socketIO for a project, using [flasfka](https://github.com/travel-intelligence/flasfka)

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/travel-intelligence/flasfka), I am running the flasfka server

```
flasfka-serve
```

and then doing a simple POST call to test it

```
curl -X POST --data-binary '{"messages": ["msg1", "msg2"]}' "http://127.0.0.1:5000/my-topic/"
```

But getting error

```
kafka.errors.InvalidTopicError: [Error 17] InvalidTopicError: b'my-topic'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2018 11:31:33] "POST /my-topic/ HTTP/1.1" 500
```

It looks like there is 500 internal server error which is too generic to pinpoint.

Any suggestion on resolving it? Maybe using a package last updated 3 years ago is a bad idea to begin with.